# Error:Cannot set readonly property: proguardFiles for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType

Tags: android

I am trying to run an AR sample app from: https://artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=4_Android:android_examples

I tried to open the project ARSimpleProj. But it gives me this error:

```
Error:Cannot set readonly property: proguardFiles for class: com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType
```

I am using Android Studio 2.2.2 and Gradle 2.14.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the same error last a few hours. I solved by changing build type as follow -

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

After that I deleted all ndk imported code line. So my build.gradle of aRSimple is -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimple"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            //Integer type incremented by 1 for every release, major or minor, to Google store
            versionName = "1.0" //Real fully qualified major and minor release description

            buildConfigFields.with {
                //Defines fields in the generated Java BuildConfig class, in this case, for
                create() {           //default config, that can be accessed by Java code
                    type = "int"     //e.g. "if (1 == BuildConfig.VALUE) { /*do something*/}".
                    name = "VALUE"
                    //See: [app or lib]/build/generated/source/buildConfig/[package path]/
                    value = "1"      //     BuildConfig.java
                }
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
    }



    }


dependencies {
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1' //Only required when the target device API level is greater than
    compile project(':aRBaseLib')
}                                                       //the compile and target of the app being deployed to the device
```

Then I create and copied all the .so library file into the jnilibs in applicaion main folder as show in fig

[fig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRNqB.png)

Then run yours. 
I don't know this is the solution for this. But the errors go and project run without errors. Tell me if you find any other solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't had any solution aside from yours. It is my first time to use this SDk.

Answer (score 8):

According to
[this description](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-0.2.x---0.4.0) , in version 0.4.0 , '+=' was desabled and instead use ".add()" for it . 
So make the statement

`proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.pro')`

change to

`proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))`

and the error will disappear

The build.gradle file now looks like the following ...note the changes..there are 2-3 changes done
but now working absolutely fine.The code is below:-

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application' 

    model {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion = 23
            buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "org.artoolkit.ar.samples.ARSimple"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 15
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 22
            versionCode = 1
            //Integer type incremented by 1 for every release, major or minor, to Google store
            versionName = "1.0" //Real fully qualified major and minor release description

            buildConfigFields.with {
                //Defines fields in the generated Java BuildConfig class, in this case, for
                create() {           //default config, that can be accessed by Java code
                    type = "int"     //e.g. "if (1 == BuildConfig.VALUE) { /*do something*/}".
                    name = "VALUE"
                    //See: [app or lib]/build/generated/source/buildConfig/[package path]/
                    value = "1"      //     BuildConfig.java
                }
            }
        }
    }

    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.pro'))
        }
    }

    android.productFlavors {
    }

    android.sources {
        main{
            jni {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/nop']
                }
            }
        }
        main{
            jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':aRBaseLib')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the files from [Github](https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5) fixed it for me. I followed the short read me that they had in order to link the files to where you have saved the SDK and reopened from within that directory. I couldn't get the above answer to work for me. Perhaps something changed as I had all the .so libs; else I did it wrong.